# blocking mac address query

Tags: wireless, networking

I tried to use the following command from iw tools: `dev <devname> station set <MAC address> plink_action <open|block>` like this : `iw dev wlan0 station set 30:14:4a:3e:f0:98 plink_action block`. And I get the following error: `command failed: Invalid argument (-22)` . I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is for my adhoc (ibss) mesh network so that I can force multihopping.

I am using PC Alix boards, and an Atheros chipset and ATH5k driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source <mac_addr> -j DROP`  is the way to go. A very very useful tool this.